# Easier way to write Maps/Sets in ES6 (compiler or syntactic sugar?)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I never understood why we can't write ES6 Maps like this:

```
new Map({
    ['ArrayAsKey']: {foo:bar}
})
```

Is there some way to achieve this? Or any method that makes using these newer data-structures more pleasant.

Comment: What is that syntax meant to do?, it's confusing to me so it's maybe why it's not done.

Answer (score 3):

> I never understood why we can't write ES6 Maps like this:
>
> ```
> new Map({
>     ['ArrayAsKey']: {foo:bar}
> })
> ```

because this syntax would only allow strings for keys; all other types will be stringified.

But you can pass a list of key-value pairs:

```js
const a = {foo: 13};
const b = {foo: 13};

const map = new Map([
  [a, "const a"],
  [b, "const b"]
]);

console.log(map.get(a), a);
console.log(map.get(b), b);
```